# when I convert buffer array to string I get unreadable symbol or character

Tags: java, android, string, network-programming, java-io

I spent two days trying solving this problem, but I don't understand what is the problem. I developed simple  server app on android. and  I sent request to the server app ( which below),  I read the incoming message by using buffer array , then I want to  convert the buffer array to string and save it as  txt file. My goal is I want do some matching string on receiving messages.
But the problem is I see characters like:

"%��! �zy�*]��{�u3�gy�+2%��Y���5ҟ��(��������(c�����$|lC���ksm��v���e�"

```
   private InputStream in;

     try {
        byte[] buff = new byte[LIMIT];
        int got;
        while ((got = in.read(buff)) > -1) {
                String msg = new String(buff, 0, got);
                saveToFile(msg);
        }
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
        ignore.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Can anybody help  and explain to me why I get these characters? By the way, 
I also tried using decode like:

```
String msg = new String(buff, 0, got, "UFT8");
```

But nothing changed,  I got the same characters ���

Comment: Looks OK to me. What makes you sure this isn't what is being sent? And how are you saving it? But would be better to avoid creating a String at all, and just call `write(buff, 0, got)` to save the data.

Comment: I save it as follow,     public static void saveToFile(String msg) {
        try {
        Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("trafifc.txt", true)));
     
      
       
        out.write("Message:");
        out.write(msg);
        //out.write("");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } @EJP

Comment: Don't post it as a comment; [edit] your post with any additional info.

Comment: Well don't do that, it's incredibly inefficient to open and close a file per message. Keep the file open: use a `BufferedOutputStream` around a `FileOutputStream`, not a `Writer`, and use the call I indicated above. And answer the question about what is being sent. Or, if you're certain the input is text, read it with a `Reader`, not an `InputStream`.

Comment: Thank you @EJP for your help. now, it is woking :) I take in consider your comments  about  an  inefficient to open and close a file per message. thanks for your comment

Comment: It is now working how? with the  `FileOutputStream`, or with the `Reader`? You should either post the solution here, as a comment or answer, or else delete the questio, as it's of no further use here.

Comment: I used FileOutputStream. then as you mentioned I  just passed buff instead  string to write(buff, 0, got). I will post the solution as soon as I finished my work @EJP